# Angular 11 And Zuul Gateway develop problem with hot reloading

Tags: angular, webpack, netflix-zuul

I am developing an Angular application with Angular 11. Application is running in http://localhost:4200 in dev mode. The backend application is behind a gateway configured with Zuul 2.2 with url `https://localhost:8447`. When ask for the login page (or any other page) I see some requests to `wss://localhost:8447`, that are rejected and this error appears in the browser:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8447/ui/sockjs-node/197/jxkw5ek0/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

I suppose that Angular is trying to do hot mode reloading against Node server in 4200 port.

I did this modification in `package.json`

```json
"start": "ng serve --base-href /ui/ --public-host http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node"
```

But in this case, this error appears in the browser:

```
zone-evergreen.js:2845 GET https://localhost:4200/ui/sockjs-node/info?t=1611158080859 net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

The URL `https://localhost:4200` is incorrect, because Angular is deployed in a non secure port

Is there anything wrong? Is this due to a bug in Webpack or Angular?

```
package.json
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --base-href /ui/",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

```
angular.json

{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "otaplatform-ui": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/xxxxxxx",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "xxxxxxxxxxx:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "xxxxxxxxxxx:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "xxxxxxxxxxx:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "xxxxxxxxxxx:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "xxxxxxxxxxx:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to use --ssl flag

```
"start": "ng serve --base-href /ui/ --ssl --ssl-key ssl/localhost.key --ssl-cert ssl/localhost.crt --public-host localhost:4200"
```

and redirect to https://localhost:4200 in Zuul to solve the problem.

It is not the best solution, but it works. Maybe this problem is due to Angular 11 version, I did not check it